# VideoCapture in OpenCV iOS vs OpenCV C++

Tags: ios, opencv, video-capture

I'm trying to open a stored video.

In a C++ project using OpenCV 3.0 with the following code:

```
cv::VideoCapture capture;
if(capture.open("IMG_1181.MOV")){
    cout << "opened";
}else{
    cout << "not opened";
}
```

I can open the video file with no problem, and the output line gives `opened`.

However if I use the exact same video with the exact same code but the iOS version of OpenCV set to compile as Objective-C++, the output line gives `not opened`.  I don't get any errors.  The video just won't open.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, one can't simply open a file with just its name (or at least I can't). First you would need to get the bundle's path, then use that path to load the file. As an example:

```
// get main app bundle
NSBundle * appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

// constant file name
NSString * videoName = @"IMG_1181";
NSString * videoType = @"MOV";

// get file path in bundle
NSString * videoPathInBundle = [appBundle pathForResource: videoName ofType: videoType];

// convert NSString to std::string
std::string videoPath([videoPathInBundle UTF8String]);

// load video
video =  cv::VideoCapture(videoPath);
```